# Is there a way to disable right-click in QGIS when drawing

Tags: qgis, polygon, map-drawing

I would like to know if I can **disable** the **rightclick** in **QGIS**. The issue is that I draw polygons that are kind of big, let's say 4000 polygon points. And as you know rightclick brakes the drawing process and you can save or delete what you draw.

But drawing 4k points is terrible for a hand. So it often happens to me that I accidentially click the right mouse button though I was not finished with drawing.

Is there a way to disable it. I mean instead of right click maybe something in the menu to stop drawing?

Comment: When I have a very complicated polygon to digitize, I like to draw the polygon in separate pieces, then combine the pieces using the Merge tool on the Advanced Digitizing toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do to prevent the drawing from being finished too early:

1. click on the pencil to deactivate the editing mode
2. perform any move or zoom functions
3. click on the pencil to enable the editing mode
4. click on the new polygon icon to resume editing

Using the mousewheel to zoom in and out is also safe.

If it gets too complicated, I usually draw a rough guess of the polygon (avoiding any snapping), save the object and then use the `add vertex` tool in higher zoom levels to add or move the polygon vertices into the exact position.

Comment: Is there a way to draw a polygon and say later to keep on drawing as if it was never stopped? But NOT draw a new polygon. Btw: your way does not really help because there rightclicks can still happen.

Comment: Only with my second method: Add the remaining vertices manually. Then rightclicks have no effect.

Comment: Well your second way would be a preprocess right? So you draw something, but now the correct line, and afterwards you draw the points to the right place. And maybe also adding new ones? Is that right?

Comment: Yes, or start with the usual way until you can not get further without extra operations. Or you have accidentially hit rightclick.

Answer (score 1):

One option is that you instead of drawing the feature as a polygon, you draw it as a line. If you accidentally hit right button, you use the Reshape tool as described above by clicking on the end point of the line. This tool is much more useful when drawing lines compared to polygons. You can just continue drawing until you're back where you started (or accidentally hit right button, then continue again).

**Note!** Make sure you don't click at the first point of the line when you're done since it will automatically just keep the part you just drew.

When you're done you convert your polyline layer to polygons with `Polylines to polygon` function in QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try just simply to start digitizing your polygon, and after 100-200 points you stop it. And after you can continue with the reshape feature button. 
Or another way is to make with the snap to function features, and if it happens to close the feature with the right click, you could just merge the features.

Answer (score 0):

Disable right click with MurGee Mouse Disabler

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user please take the [tour].  A good answer should include detail about what steps are required and how it answers the question.  Please [edit] your answer to expand on what you are suggesting.